# Focus on specfic part through links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i've an question related to focus specfic part of the page.
i've 2 files
one is header file
one is main file
header file contains navbar
when i click on navbar's link
it should go to that part of main page.

For example
i clicked on middle from the navbar dropdown
then the main page should to go middle of the page
remember:
my header is an other file.

```
<script>
 $('#inter').click(function (evt){
   $("#third").focus();
   evt.preventDefault();
 });
 </script>
```

inter is basically id of that anchor in header file
and script is in main file

Comment: You need to point your anchor link to a div id but you need to first show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: @AndrewLyndem updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using hashtags.

```
<p><a id="myAnchor" href="#part2">Click to move</a></p>
```

please  refer this [fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/ianclark001/aShQL/) for detailed implementation

Hope this helps